# What version of java and jdk that will fix the error cannot be cast to sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment

Tags: java, java-11, openjdk-11

We recently upgraded our Linux Ubuntu to 5.4.0-1058-gcp ( GCP VM )and our mobile app started to malfunction.

Is this java version going to help fix the issue?

```
openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04, mixed mode, sharing)


Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
sun.java2d.HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment cannot be cast to 
sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit$3.run(WToolkit.java:834)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: "Headless" normally indicates pure server install without desktop, and indeed it is `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM`. If the Ubuntu is a desktop version (as opposed to a server version), you should be able to install a desktop (Open)JDK. Desktop meaning: having a GUI, window manager. Try a small Hello World GUI.

Comment: @JoopEggen, it's a dedicated pure server VM.  Should I proceed to install the OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM to fix the problem?

Comment: And still there is an AWT event queue started, a GUI? I hope you can find more in the stack trace, further below. Normally one would have assumed a transition to modular could break things, but this is weird. Did you start some server monitoring GUI?

Comment: @JoopEggen, there is no monitoring running in the GCP VM server.  It's only this one java application.

Comment: The problem is not the headless mode, the problem is the attempt to use a *Windows* implementation of the UI framework under *Linux*. Since the line number in the stacktrace does not match the OpenJDK 11.0.13’s `WToolkit` source code, it apparently is not only the wrong toolkit for this operating system, but also not the toolkit shipped with this Java version. Seems like someone is trying really hard to mess up this environment.

Comment: @Holger thanks for jumping in. `sun.awt.windows` seems to point to non-OpenJDK, Oracle for Windows. One maybe could find something under /usr/lib/jvm, but I am not that experienced.

Comment: @JoopEggen the class `sun.awt.windows.WToolkit` does exist in OpenJDK 11, but as said, its line 834 does not contain a matching type cast to produce this `ClassCastException`.